# rotating the xy plane of a 3D graph in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I plotted a 3D graph with gnu plot, with the following commands

```
set term png 
#set term post enh color eps font "Times-Roman, 15"  
set output "order.png"
#set title ""
set key outside right bottom vertical reverse enhanced samplen 2 spacing 1.0 width 2 height 1 
#set key font "Times-Roman,15"
set xlabel "\eta"
set ylabel "r"
set zlabel "\rho_0"
set xyplane 0
#set view 120,50
set grid
set grid ztics
set xtics 0.5
set ytics 0.5
set ztics 0.05
set tics font "Times-Roman,15"
set tics scale 0.5
set xrange [0:1] noreverse nowriteback
set yrange [0:1] noreverse nowriteback
set zrange [0:0.12] noreverse nowriteback
splot "order0.txt" u 1:2:3
```

and the plot is :
[image]
but I want it to be like the original plot(which is taken from a peper):
[image]

I searched the internet, but I just found

> set view

which doesn't produce the one that I want.

Comment: How does your data look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds as if you would like to rotate the plot around the z-axis so that the r-axis is in "front". The second number in the "set view" command will do that. Try "set view 45 300". Sorry if you meant something else.